# Alert in the view before navigation to other view through ondisaappeaing event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an android application in xamarin.forms with two view.While clicking on navigation back button in second view I need to show an alert the second view.

```
protected async override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();

            if (_purchaseViewModel.ItemsCartList!=null && _purchaseViewModel.ItemsCartList.Count > 0)
            {
                var buyItems= await Helper.AskUserBuyOrDiscard("Information","Do you want to buy the selected items.");
                if (buyItems)
                {
                    _purchaseViewModel.DoneCommandHandler();
                }
            }
        }
```

here the alert is appearing in first view.How can I dispaly the alert first and navigate to previous page next?

Comment: Move base.OnDisappearing() under your logic. On different platforms it may behave differently. Check the official doc.

Comment: Thanks for response@EvZ,I will check.

Comment: While moving  base.OnDisappearing() under my logic its not woking

Comment: Check this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63531/how-to-get-navigation-back-button-event-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/ this link will be helpful, you will find the sample code also.